# C - Missing .dll library when .exe is copied to another computer

Tags: c

I used `MySQL Connector C 6.1` api in C.

I linked all the header files, libraries etc in the Code blocks IDE and when I try to compile the program,it works and I am able to run the program. But when I copy the .exe file to another computer, a warning comes saying that `libmysql.dll is missing.` When I copy that `libmysql.dll` file along with the program,it works fine. But how to avoid that? Is there a way to make it run without copying .dll file?

Comment: the first problem is you're using windows

Comment: @self why is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

If your program depends on a .dll (which stands for dynamic link library) then there is no way to run without that .dll being present on the system.  This is because there is code in the library that your program depends on.  An alternative would be to build your program with a static version of the library, a .lib file.

Comment: And the folder also has a .lib file and when i try to link it, code blocks doesn't show. It shows only .dll file.